# how to animate a bouncing ball on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, draw, setinterval

Hi I've just started coding Java and HTML, etc, so I tend to struggle at times. Hence I have joined StackOverflow for your help (Be nice to me please :) )

I'm trying to animate using `setInterval()` and draw method to create a bouncing ball which moves by a number of pixels in each frame. When it hits an edge it should bounce back by reversing the direction of the relevant horizontal or vertical pixel velocity.

Here is what has been done so far, my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
  <title>Canvas Example</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src='myanim.js' defer></script>
  <style type=text/css>
    #mycanvas {border:1px solid #000000}
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <canvas id=mycanvas width=600 height=400>Canvas Not Supported
  </canvas>
  </body>
  </html>
```

My JavaScript:

```
var canvas=document.getElementById('mycanvas');
var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
var timer;
var fillColour = '#FF0000';
var strokeColour = '#FFFFFF';
var x=0; var y=0;
function frameRate(fps) {
 timer = window.setInterval(updateCanvas,1000/fps);
}
function noLoop() {
 window.clearInterval(timer);
}
function updateCanvas(){
if (Math.random()>0.5)x+=2; else x-=2;
if (Math.random()>0.5)y+=2; else y-=2;
ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
draw();
}
function draw(){
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(canvas.width/2+x,canvas.height/2+y,100,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();
}
ctx.strokeStyle=strokeColour;
ctx.fillStyle=fillColour;
frameRate(50);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6EFqk/265/

I've been helped out by the `math.random` as I don't understand it. Can someone help me out on how to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Now, what's wrong with the code? What it does differently you've expected?

Comment: Hi nothing is wrong with the code, its just the start of what i want it to do, which is to have the ball animate around the canvas, which is what i am stuck with not knowing how

Comment: You've to create a random _direction_ at first (angle). Then follow that direction until hit a wall. Calculate a new direction and follow that etc ...  Currently a new position is calculated randomly all the time, you ball doesn't follow a straight line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Animating a bouncing ball**

Below is an example of a simple bouncing ball. This answer is partly from another answer, but your question title is better suited to being found.

**The Main Loop.**

To animate you need to have a main loop. This is the function that is called once every time you need to update and draw everything you need onto the canvas. This update is normally called a frame. Then number of times the main loop is called a second is called the frame rate. The typical frame rate of HTML is 60 frames per second or lower. HTML5 provides a special event call requestAnimationFrame that is designed for animations and fires at the best time for you to run the main loop.

```
function mainLoop(){
    // clear the canvas
    // update the position of all the stuff in the animation

    // then request the next animation frame
    window.requestAnimationFrame( mainLoop ); // pase it the name of your main loop
    // the main loop is done. Exiting lets the browser know yo are done and 
    // it presents the redrawn canvas to the screen.
}
```

To start the animation just call the mainloop after you have everything set up

```
// starting the animation
mainLoop(); // call main loop
```

Request animation frame will do its best to maintain an even frame rate. It will also slow down if your mainloop takes to long.

**Bouncing a ball**

Below is an example of how to simulate a single bouncing ball and to correctly handle simple collisions will surfaces parallel to the canvas sides.

It demonstrates how to change the frame rate by switching between `requestAnimationFrame` and `setTimeout` to call the main loop function.

It has an example of drawing an image, and adding motion blur (NOTE motion blur is GPU (graphics processing unit) intensive and will not work well on large numbers of objects.)

**Inter frame movement**

The correct way to reflect an object from a surface.

You must take into account that the ball is moving between frames and that the collision may have happened at any time during the previous frame. The ball's distance from the wall after the collision is dependent on when during the previous frame it hit the wall. This is important if the ball moves slowly or quickly.

```
var dx = 10; // delta x velocity of object in pixels
var wx = 10; // width of object in pixels
var px = 90;  // position of object in pixels
var wallX = 105; // position of wall


px += dx;  // move the ball. Its position is now  100.
           // its right side is at px + wx = 110.
// test if it has it the wall
if(px+wx > wallX){
    dx = -dx; // reflect delta x
    // The object is 5 pixel into the wall.
    // The object has hit the wall some time during the last frame
    // We need to adjust the position as the ball may have been
    // traveling away from the wall for some time during the last frame.
    var dist = (px+wx)-wallX; // get the distance into the wall
    px -= dist*2; // the object hit the wall at position 95 and has been 
                  // traveling away since then so it is easy to just 
                  // subtract 2 times the distance the ball entered the wall
    // the above two lines can be done in one
    // px -= ((px+wx)-wallX)*2;
}
```

**Why it matters**

Below is a simulation of a ball bouncing inside the canvas.

To illustrate that the ball is moving between frames it has been motion blurred to show its motion between frames. Please note this is not the perfect solution as the bounce is assumed to occur while the ball is in linear motion while infact it is in freefall and under constant acceleration. But it still conserves energy.

In the correct test the height the ball bounces back to, stays around the same over time. No energy is lost or gained.

Right click to turn off the inter frame adjustment and you will notice that the ball begins to decrease its height each frame. This is because at each collision the ball loses a little energy because it motion during the previous frame is not taken into account when positioning it after the collision test. It will settle down to a constant rate when the collision occurres at precisely the frame time. When that will be is very hard to determine in advance.

Left click to slow the simulation frame rate, left click again to return to normal.

The code below is not really part of the answer, it is there to demonstrate the effect of not correctly adjusting the position during collision test on the overall accuracy of the simulation.

```js
// helper functions. NOT part of the answer
var canvas = document.getElementById("canV"); 
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var mouseButton = 0;
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown',function(event){mouseButton = event.which;});
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup'  ,function(){mouseButton = 0;});
canvas.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e){ e.preventDefault();}, false);
var currentSurface = ctx;
var createImage = function (w, h) {// create an canvas image of size w,h and attach context 2d
    var image = document.createElement("canvas");  
    image.width = w;
    image.height = h !== undefined?h:w; 
    currentSurface = image.ctx = image.getContext("2d"); 
    return image;
}  
var setColour = function (fillC, strokeC, lineW) { 
    currentSurface.fillStyle = fillC !== undefined ? fillC : currentSurface.fillStyle;
    currentSurface.strokeStyle = strokeC !== undefined ? strokeC : currentSurface.strokeStyle;
    currentSurface.lineWidth = lineW !== undefined ? lineW : currentSurface.lineWidth;
}
var circle = function(x,y,r,how){
    currentSurface.beginPath();
    currentSurface.arc(x,y,r,0,Math.PI*2);
    how = how.toLowerCase().replace(/[os]/g,"l"); // how to draw
    switch(how){
        case "f":  // fill
            currentSurface.fill();
            break;
        case "l":
            currentSurface.stroke();
            break;
        case "lf":
            currentSurface.stroke();
            currentSurface.fill();
            break;
        case "fl":
            currentSurface.fill();
            currentSurface.stroke();
            break;
    }
}
function createGradImage(size,col1,col2){
    var image = createImage(size);
    var g = currentSurface.createLinearGradient(0,0,0,currentSurface.canvas.height);
    g.addColorStop(0,col1);
    g.addColorStop(1,col2);
    currentSurface.fillStyle = g;
    currentSurface.fillRect(0,0,currentSurface.canvas.width,currentSurface.canvas.height);    
    return image;
}
function createColouredBall (ballR,col) {
    var ball = createImage(ballR*2);
    var unit = ballR/100;
    setColour("black");
    circle(ballR,ballR,ballR,"f");
    setColour("hsl("+col+",100%,30%)");
    circle(ballR-unit*3,ballR-unit*3,ballR-unit*7,"f");
    setColour("hsl("+col+",100%,50%)");
    circle(ballR-unit*10,ballR-unit*10,ballR-unit*16,"f");
    setColour("White");
    circle(ballR-unit*50,ballR-unit*50,unit*16,"f");
    
    return ball;
}
//===================================    
//    _                          
//   /_\  _ _  ____ __ _____ _ _ 
//  / _ \| ' \(_-< V  V / -_) '_|
// /_/ \_\_||_/__/\_/\_/\___|_|  
//                              
// ==================================
// Answer code

// lazy coder variables
var w = canvas.width;
var h = canvas.height;

// ball is simulated 5cm 
var pixSize = 0.24; // in millimeters for simulation

// Gravity is 9.8 ms^2 so convert to pixels per frame squared
// Assuming constant 60 frames per second. ()
var gravity = 9800*pixSize/60; 
gravity *= 0.101; // because Earth's gravity is stupidly large let's move to Pluto

// ball 5cm 
var ballR = (25/pixSize)/2;          // radius is 2.5cm for 5cm diamiter ball
var ballX = w/2;                     // get center of canvas
var ballY = ballR+3;                 // start at the top
var ballDX = (Math.random()-0.5)*15; // start with random x speed
ballDX += ballDX < 0 ? -5 : 5;       // make sure it's not too slow
var ballDY = 0;                      // star with no downward speed;
var ballLastX = ballX;
var ballLastY = ballY;

//create an image of the Ball
var ball = createColouredBall(ballR,Math.floor(Math.random()*360)); // create an image of ball

// create a background. Image is small as it does not have much detail in it
var background = createGradImage(16,"#5af","#08C");
// time to run for


// Function to draw ball without motion blur
// draws the ball with out motion blurred. 
// image is the image to draw
// px and py are the x and y position to draw the ball
var drawImage = function(image , px, py){
    ctx.drawImage(image, px, py);
}


// draws the ball motion blurred. This introduces extra complexity
var drawMotionBlur = function(image, px, py, dx, dy, steps){
    var i, sx, sy;
    sx = dx / steps;
    sy = dy / steps;
    px -= dx; // move back to start position
    py -= dy; 
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1 / (steps * 0.8); // set alpha to slightly higher for each step
    for(i = 0; i < steps; i+= 1){
        ctx.drawImage(image, px + i * sx, py + i * sy);
    }
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1; // reset alpha
    
}
// style for text
ctx.fillStyle = "white";
ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.lineJoin = "round"; // stop some letters getting ears.
ctx.lineWidth = 3;
ctx.textBaseline = "bottom";
var textCenterX = w/2;
var maxHeight = Infinity;
var lastMaxHeight = ballY;
var slowMotion = false;  // slow motion flag
var frameTravel = true;  // use frame travel in collision test 
const bSteps = 10;  // the fixed motion blur steps
var update = function(){
    var str, blurSteps;
    blurSteps = 10;  // motion blur ball render steps. This varies depending on the the collision inter frame time. 
     
    if(mouseButton === 1){
        slowMotion = ! slowMotion;
        mouseButton = 0;
    }
    if(mouseButton === 3){
        frameTravel = ! frameTravel;
        ballX = w / 2;                     // get center of canvas
        ballY = ballR + 3;                 // start at the top
        ballDY = 0;                      // start at 0 y speed
        mouseButton = 0;
    }
    // clear the canvas with background canvas image
    ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, w, h);
    
    ballDY += gravity; // acceleration due to grav
    // add deltas to ball position
    ballX += ballDX; 
    ballY += ballDY;
    // test for collision on left and right walls. Need to 
    // adjust for motion blur
    if (ballX < ballR) {
        ballDX = -ballDX; // refect delta x
        if (frameTravel) { // if using frame travel time
            // blur the outward traveling ball only for the time it has been traveling away
            blurSteps = Math.ceil(10 * ((ballX - ballR) / -ballDX));
            // get position it should have traveled since
            ballX -= (ballX - ballR) * 2;
        }else{
            ballX = ballR; // move ball to touching wall
            blurSteps = 1; // there is no outward motion
        }
    } else
    if (ballX > w - ballR) {
        ballDX = -ballDX;
        if (frameTravel) { // if using frame travel time
            // blur the outward traveling ball only for the time it has been traveling away
            blurSteps = Math.ceil(10 * ((ballX - (w - ballR)) / -ballDX));
            ballX -= (ballX - (w - ballR)) * 2;
        }else{
            ballX = w - ballR; // move ball to touching wall
            blurSteps = 1; // there is no outward motion
        }
    }

    // Test ball hit ground
    if (ballY > h - ballR) {
        ballDY = -ballDY;
        // to show max height
        lastMaxHeight = maxHeight;
        maxHeight = Infinity;
        if (frameTravel) { // if using frame travel time
            // blur the outward traveling ball only for the time it has been traveling away
            blurSteps = Math.ceil(10 * ((ballY - (h - ballR)) / -ballDY));
            ballY -= (ballY - (h - ballR)) * 2;
        }else{
            ballY = h - ballR; // move ball to touching wall
            blurSteps = 1; // there is no outward motion
        }
    }     
   
    // draw the ball motion blured
    drawMotionBlur(
        ball,                    // image to draw
        ballX - ballR,             // offset radius
        ballY - ballR,
        ballDX * (blurSteps / bSteps),  // speed and adjust for bounced
        ballDY * (blurSteps / bSteps),
        blurSteps                // number of blurs
    );

    // show max height. Yes it is min but everything is upside down.
    maxHeight = Math.min(maxHeight,ballY);
    lastMaxHeight = Math.min(ballY,lastMaxHeight);

    // show max height
    ctx.font = "12px arial black";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, lastMaxHeight - ballR);
    ctx.lineTo(w, lastMaxHeight - ballR);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fillText("Max height.", 40, lastMaxHeight - ballR + 6);


    str = ""; // display status string
    if(slowMotion){   // show left click help
        str += "10fps."
        ctx.fillText("click for 60fps.", textCenterX, 43);
    }else{
        str += "60fps."
        ctx.fillText("click for 10fps.", textCenterX, 43);
    }

    if(frameTravel){ // show mode and right click help
        str += " Mid frame collision.";
        ctx.fillText("Right click for Simple collision", textCenterX,55);
    }else{
        str += " Simple collision.";
        ctx.fillText("Right click for mid frame collision", textCenterX,55);
    }

    // display help text
    ctx.font = "18px arial black";  
    ctx.strokeText(str, textCenterX, 30);
    ctx.fillText(str, textCenterX, 28);

    if(slowMotion){
        setTimeout(update, 100); // show in slow motion
    }else{
        requestAnimationFrame(update); // request next frame (1/60) seconds from now
    }

    // all done
}
update(); // to start the ball rolling
```

```css
.canC { width:500px;  height:500px;}
```

```html
<canvas class="canC" id="canV" width=500 height=500></canvas>
```