# Ball stops bouncing after 4-5 seconds

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

Here is the javascript:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
  ax = 50,
  ay = 50,
  avx = 5,
  avy = 2,
  radius = 50;

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

function drawArc() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.arc(ax, ay, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
};

function update() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawArc();
  ax += avx;
  ay -= avy;
  avy -= 0.2;

  if (ay + radius >= canvas.height) {
    avy *= -0.8;
    avx *= 0.9;
  };

  if (ax + radius >= canvas.width) {
    avx = -avx;
  };

  if (ax - radius <= 0) {
    avx = -avx;
  };
}
setInterval(update, 10);
```

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#canvas {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Here at Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/milosdacic/qh1ha085/

I don't know why this is happening, code seems fine.

I have done this thing before but now it won't work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want it to bounce for ever?

Comment: What did you expect to happen? You have coded that on every floor-hit, the speed of the ball is reduced (friction). So it is only normal the ball stops moving after a while.

Comment: If you dont want to loose height you need to keep track of all the kinetic energy at each bounce. This answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/34187884/3877726 demonstrates how to do a simple bouncing ball the does not loose energy over time. http://stackoverflow.com/a/34187884/3877726

Comment: I don't want from ball to bounce forever i just want to stop bouncing naturally, not just freeze at one moment.

Comment: By reducing avy by  0.8 every time, you are trying to simulate a energy loose where loosing energy is not linear in real. However you can change it to 0.9 or more for a longer animation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer is you are getting many hits because you are not moving the ball up away from the ground. The next frame it is still impacting the ground and as you reduce its speed it just bogs down..

Add this after line 29 of your fiddle.

```
ay = canvas.height - radius;
```

[For more on bouncing a ball](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34187884/3877726)

Comment: Thank you very much. You guys here are awesome :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess You wanted this:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
  ax = 50,
  ay = 50,
  avx = 5,
  avy = 2,
  radius = 50;

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

function drawArc() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.arc(ax, ay, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
};

var hitTheGround = 0;
function update() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawArc();
  ax += avx;
  ay -= avy;
  avy -= 0.2;

  if (ay + radius >= canvas.height) {
    avy *= -0.8;
    avx *= 0.9;
  }
  
  if (ax + radius >= canvas.width) {
    avx = -avx;
  }

  if (ax - radius <= 0) {
    avx = -avx;
  }
  
  if(ay + radius >= canvas.height - 3) {
    hitTheGround++;
  }
  else {
    hitTheGround = 0;  
  }
  
  if(hitTheGround == 100) { // if it jumps near the ground too frequently
    return setTimeout(function() {clearInterval(interval)}, 1000);
  }
}
var interval = setInterval(update, 10);
```

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#canvas {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Little bit dirty fix to stop calling update after than it jumps (vibrates) near the ground N times.

Comment: I don't want infinite bouncing i just want to bounce normally and not to freeze after couple of floor-hits. Just watch ball bouncing for a 5-6 seconds and you will see that at one point ball just freeze into the floor.

Comment: @MilosDacic check now :)

Comment: Hmm, not working. I'll upload a video so you can see what is the problem. Maybe it is just on my computer :(

Comment: @MilosDacic have little patience, I'm stopping animation after 1 sec than it vibrates on ground, feel free to change setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first of, the code that works.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#canvas {
  background-color: black;
}
    </style>
    <script>
function drawArc() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.arc(ax, ay, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
};

function update() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawArc();
  ax += avx;
  ay -= avy;
  avy -= 0.2;

  if (ay + radius >= canvas.height) {
    avy *= -0.8;
    avx *= 0.9;
  };

  if (ax + radius >= canvas.width) {
    avx = -avx;
  };

  if (ax - radius <= 0) {
    avx = -avx;
  };
}

function onload()
{
canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ax = 50;
ay = 50;
avx = 5;
avy = 2;
radius = 50;

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
setInterval(update, 10);
}
    </script>
    <style>
    </style>
  </head>
  <body onload="onload()">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

Second, what the problem is/was. I think the biggest issue I had was that the code you offered had variables and actions in the global context which were dependent on the page elements which had not yet been created. This meant that the variables for canvas and cxt couldn't be created because the canvas tag hadn't been created yet. I put all of that into a function I could call when the page had loaded and everything worked fine from there. Now when that function is called the canvas already exists and you can use it to create the context and do everything else.

Third based on the question title you want to know why it stopped bouncing. I think you have correctly created a bouncing ball which bounces off the walls and floors, but suffers a lost of energy due to gravity and a non-elastic collision with the ground. Personally, I have not worked through the code, but it looks great. Why would you change it. If you want it to keep bouncing forever, then the collisions with the walls and floors need to be 100% elastic--this means that you don't lose any energy and your ball bounces as high as it ever was before. In your interaction with the FLOOR you use the code below. This has a dampening effect and eventually drops your ball to zero energy.

```
avy *= -0.8;//could be -1
avx *= 0.9;//could be 1
```

That, however, creates another problem. The code you are using needs dampening or the ball just bounces higher on every bounce. This is because you are accelerating on this line and GAINING ENERGY.

```
avy -= 0.2;
```

One of your other answers suggested you reduce the dampening, but not remove it entirely by changing this one line. You would have to tune this to make it have the behavior you want.

```
avy *= -0.8;//-0.8 is too little? -1 is too much
```

LAST EDIT, I PROMISE. I actually had a lot of fun with this. The problem is not so trivial that you can just put in psuedo-physics and get a good simulation of a ball bouncing. Even when you put in all the right equations you still get a small perpetual bounce because that is what happens in real life. When the ball is moving slowly enough and is close enough to the floor the other forces (not gravity, but strong, weak and electro-magnetic attraction) dominate and cause the ball to stop moving. So, I took one more swipe at it and improved the physics a lot. It's not perfect, but at some point you have to ask is the FIDELITY of the simulation more important than smoothing the behavior to match what I want to see. Hope this helps.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#canvas {
  background-color: black;
}
    </style>
    <script>
function drawArc() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.arc(xPos, yPos, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
};

function update() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawArc();
  var dx = xVel*timeStep;
  var dy = yVel*timeStep;

  if(yVel<radius && yVel>-radius && canvas.height-(yPos+radius) < .1)
  {
    yVel = 0;
    yPos = canvas.height-radius;
    dy=0;

    //friction affects xVel
    xVel *= fFloor;
  }
  else if (yPos + dy + radius >= canvas.height) {
    //you will be below the floor; there is a bounce

    //find the rest of the falling interval
    var remainingY = canvas.height-(yPos+radius);

    //find the rest of the time step    
    var remainingTime = remainingY / yVel;

    //add acceleration for that time
    yVel += gravity * remainingTime

    //friction affects xVel
    xVel *= fFloor;

    //elasticity affects yVel
    yVel *= eFloor;

    //now you are bouncing up
    //what is time up
    remainingTime = timeStep - remainingTime;

    //set final position
    yPos = canvas.height + (yVel*remainingTime) - radius;

    //add acceleration for that time
    yVel += gravity * remainingTime;
  }

  else
  {
    //do not hit the floor, falling the whole time
    yPos += dy;
    yVel += gravity * timeStep;
  }

  if (xPos + dx + radius >= canvas.width)
  {
    //hit a wall; there is a bounce

    //find the rest of the interval
    var remainingX = canvas.width-(xPos+radius);

    //find the rest of the time step    
    var remainingTime = remainingX / xVel;

    //no horizontal acceleration

    //friction affects yVel
    yVel *= fWall;

    //elasticity affects xVel
    xVel *= eWall;

    //now you are bouncing back
    //what is time up
    remainingTime = timeStep - remainingTime;

    //set final position
    xPos = canvas.width + (xVel*remainingTime) - radius;

    //no horizontal acceleration
  }
  else if (xPos + dx - radius <= 0) {
    //hit a wall; there is a bounce

    //find the rest of the interval
    var remainingX = (xPos - radius);

    //find the rest of the time step    
    var remainingTime = remainingX / xVel;

    //no horizontal acceleration

    //friction affects yVel
    yVel *= fWall;

    //elasticity affects xVel
    xVel *= eWall;

    //now you are bouncing back
    //what is time up
    remainingTime = timeStep - remainingTime;

    //set final position
    xPos = xVel*remainingTime+radius;

    //no horizontal acceleration
  }
  else {
    //never hit a wall; flying the whole time
    xPos += dx;   
  }
}

function onload()
{
canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
radius = 15;
xPos = Math.random()*(canvas.width-(2*radius))+radius;
yPos = Math.random()*(canvas.height-(2*radius))+radius;
xVel = Math.random()*100-50;
yVel = Math.random()*100-50;
gravity = 9.8;
eWall = -1;
eFloor = -.8;
fFloor = .9;
fWall = .9;
interval = 10;
timeStep = .1;//apparent time step

setInterval(update, interval);
}
    </script>
    <style>
    </style>
  </head>
  <body onload="onload()">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```