# Why is my collision code not working at all?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, game-development

I am relatively new to JavaScript, and am looking to create a platformer game for a class project. I have tried multiple ways to make a player rectangle collide with an obstacle rectangle but none have worked the way I intended. This method that I wrote myself is not functioning at all, and I have no clue why.

```js
var ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");

var fps = 50
var level = 1
var gravity = 0.5

var player = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  x_v: 0,
  y_v: 0,
  width: 20,
  height: 20,
  speed: 3,
  jump: 10,
  color: "blue"
}

const obstacle = {
  x: 0,
  y: 550,
  width: 600,
  height: 100,
  color: "black"
}

function MyKeyUpHandler(MyEvent) {
  if (MyEvent.keyCode == 37 || MyEvent.keyCode == 39) {
    player.x_v = 0
  }; // not left or right
  if (MyEvent.keyCode == 38 || MyEvent.keyCode == 40) {
    player.y_v = 0
  }; // not up or down
}


function MyKeyDownHandler(MyEvent) {
  if (MyEvent.keyCode == 37) {
    player.x_v = -player.speed
  }; // left
  if (MyEvent.keyCode == 38) {
    player.y_v = -player.jump
  }; // up
  if (MyEvent.keyCode == 39) {
    player.x_v = player.speed
  }; // right
  MyEvent.preventDefault();
}

function renderplayer() {
  player.y_v = player.y_v + gravity
  player.x = player.x + player.x_v
  player.y = player.y + player.y_v
  ctx.fillStyle = player.color
  ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height)
}

function renderobstacle() {
  ctx.fillStyle = obstacle.color
  ctx.fillRect(obstacle.x, obstacle.y, obstacle.width, obstacle.height)
}

function collision() {
  if (player.y == obstacle.y - player.height) {
    player.y_v = 0
  }
}


function frameyshit() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 600)
  renderplayer();
  renderobstacle();
  collision();
  if (player.y >= 600) {
    player.y = 1
    player.x = 1
    player.y_v = 0
  }
}

setInterval(frameyshit, 1000 / fps)
addEventListener("keydown", MyKeyDownHandler)
addEventListener("keyup", MyKeyUpHandler)
```

```html
<canvas id=myCanvas width=600 height=600 style="background-color: transparent;"> </canvas>
```

Comment: pls show a complete code + link to an online IDE so we can view and debug it.

Comment: @StavAlfi edited my post. includes the full HTML5 code, with correct (hopefully?) indentation as plaintext.
ctrl+c ctrl+v should work from there.

Comment: Add this line: `console.log(player.y - (obstacle.y - player.height));` into your collision function to see why it's not colliding.

Comment: One thing to see right away is that the collision check uses equality `==`.  What are the chances that will be right given the real-number computations?

Comment: @danh With `=` instead, it sticks the player square to the top of the obstacle, but the player cannot jump without being stuck to the top after a frame or two.

Comment: Yes, but we wouldn't change equality to assignment, we'd change it to *inequality*.  `>=`

Comment: @danh Ah, I see. The difference between assignments & equalities are tricky for me to memorize with `if` statements. Thank you a lot.

Comment: Two answers on basic collision detection. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46920237/3877726 platformer interaction example.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/34187884/3877726 Basic bouncing ball collision